# What's wrong with my xml?

Tags: xml, xpath

i have the following xml:

```
<messageContent xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" >
<Message type="MappedMessage" >
<Properties RequestId="Point-CurveRequest-8326ad44-a1cd-4a96-b4ef-1c4ad213d940"  Action="getParCurves"  EESId="EESID:NY:20100128:BASE"  Currency="USD"  Index="INX" />
<Body></Body>
</Message>
</messageContent>
```

and then i have this query:

```
var messageType = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/messageContent/Message[@type]");
```

but no matter what i've tried, i was never able to get the node that i'm looking for. Basically i'm just try to see if there is a node (named "Message") which has a "type" property inside of it.

Has anyone have any idea here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with your XML - there's something wrong with your XPath expression, though :-)

Add a XML namespace manager to your code:

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://tempuri.org/");
```

and then use that namespace manager when you do your `SelectSingleNode`:

```
var messageType = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/ns:messageContent/ns:Message[@type]", mgr);
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need to establish a namespace context on your xpath, or get rid of that xmlns="http://tempuri.org/".

Comment: Does that hold up even if its the default namespace for the entire document?

Comment: yes, thought to be perfectly sure I'd need to know what XPath package you are using -- or even what language you are in.

Comment: @bmargulies: Interesting, thats not the case when using SimpleXml under PHP - and while im not sure i dont think it matters when using DOMDcoument either... so long as its the default ns for the entire document.

Comment: this should explain more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectsinglenode.aspx

Comment: @Or A: Can you post your implementation that uses the MSDN usage example?

Answer (score 0):

NOt a straight forward but will work

```
XMLElement messageElement = (XMLElement) xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/messageContent/Message");
if(messageElement.HasAttribute("type"))
```

But the thing is if you have a node Message butdoes not contain type attribute then its not proper format of an xml.Rather i would suggest to check the content of the type attribute like below

```
XMLNode messageElement = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/messageContent/Message[@type='MappedMessage']");
if(messageElement != null)
{
//Do SOmething
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If `messageContent` is the **root** node you should omit it like: `/Message[@type]` or if you want to check the entire hierarchy of the document: `//Message[@type]`